# Attach a file to an email from public folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I want to send a file as an attachement with the email sent from my laravel application. this is how I tried to attach the file

```
 $path = public_path(). "/storage" $this->file->media;
 return $this->view('emails.newsletter')->attach($path);
```

But the email is throwing an error

> League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at path

this is the result of path variable

> /home/amir6/public_html/backend/public/storage/files/fyJ2jREuCGVC85fn.pdf

so the file exists in url/storage/files/fyJ2jREuCGVC85fn.pdf

How can I attach a file to the email?

Comment: It can't find the file. Try debugging. where does public_path() point, and what does $this->file["media"] resolve as? when you know this. Look on disk and see if a) the path makes sense, and b) that the file is there.  The methods you are using are correct, the path, is not.

Comment: if I replace the site url with this part /home/amir6/public_html/backend/public/ the file opens up.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: so you are saving the file in the wrong location?  /home/amir6/public_html/backend/public/fyJ2jREuCGVC85fn.pdf resolves is that correct?

Comment: Please add the full path where the file... "opens up" to the question.

Comment: I am not sure if I am saving the file to the wrong location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a file mime type and it worked

```
 $path = public_path().  Storage::url($this->file->media);
 return $this->view('emails.newsletter')->attach($path, [
    'as' => 'newsletter',
    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **public_path()** function try **storage_path()** function

For example:-
$path = storage_path('app/'.$this->file["media"]);
return Image::make($path )->response();

Use [Image Intervention to handle Image processing](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

Comment: now I tried storage_path($this->file["media"]);  the result is /home/amir6/public_html/backend/storage/files/fyJ2jREuCGVC85fn.pdf. but it returns the same error